# How is SHA-1 insecure if it is not vulnerable to what MD5 is?

Tags: hash, vulnerability, sha

I have been hearing a lot lately about how SHA-1 is no longer going to be used because of how weak and insecure it is, but if it is not vulnerable to collisions like MD5 is, then how is it weak and insecure? What is it vulnerable to that SHA-256 and SHA-512 are not or are less likely or easy to be?

Comment: It's not vulnerable yet, however, some attacks have shown promise. Considering it took years to move away from MD5, everyone is moving off SHA1 now so we can finish moving off it before it's compromised

Comment: According to Adi Shamir - Marc Stevens et al are working on a 2-block SHA-1 collision and have already found the first pair of blocks.

Comment: It's also about the increase in processing power since SHA1 was new - earliest reference I googled is 1993, so that's 23 years. Algorithms get more complicated over time as processing power advances to make them viable, while at the same time the risk to older algorithms goes up as brute force attacks become cheaper.

Comment: Duplicate on crypto.se: [No SHA-1 collision? Yet SHA-1 is broken?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3690/no-sha-1-collision-yet-sha-1-is-broken)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SHA-1 is vulnerable to collisions, even if no one have been publicly disclosed yet.

Some cryptographers have been working on the subject the latest years, and they estimated that [the cost of finding a collision is decreasing so much](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2012/10/when_will_we_se.html) that some attacks will be very soon within realm of possibility.

In October 2015, an important milestone was marked with [the first freestart collision example for SHA-1](https://sites.google.com/site/itstheshappening/), which is a collision for its internal function. This is not a full collision, but this is still a major improvement on the way on finding one, so they recommended to move from SHA-1 because they expect the first collisions to be found very soon.

They estimated the new [cost](https://xkcd.com/538/) of a full collision from 75K$ and 120K$, which is a 3-4 years improvement over previous estimations.

SHA-256 and SHA-512 are different algorithms, and are not affected by these theoretical attacks.

---

Update (February 2017): The first public collision on SHA-1 has been announced!

Both [this PDF](https://shattered.io/static/shattered-1.pdf) and [this one](https://shattered.io/static/shattered-2.pdf) share the same SHA-1 hash. This collision was found using [Shattered](https://shattered.io/), a new attack on SHA-1.

You can also read [Google Security Team's article](https://security.googleblog.com/2017/02/announcing-first-sha1-collision.html) on their blog.

Comment: "because the first collisions to be found very soon." - which means the NSA can probably already generate them.

Comment: @immibis: The NSA, and maybe some other actors, can already afford the cost of a collision. That's why we have an urgent need to move from SHA-1. My guess is that the NSA have already some collisions but kept its work secret, hence the first paragraph: "no one have been publicly disclosed".

Answer (score 1):

Without even considering the design details of the SHA-1 algorithm itself, it is vulnerable to collision attacks simply from having a too short output.

The output of SHA-1 is 160 bits. By using a birthday attack, it is possible to find a collision with only 2⁸⁰ invocations of SHA-1. The bitcoin system has proven that computing 2⁸⁰ hash values is feasible with current technology. In fact bitcoin computes that many hashes every two weeks.

As such any hashing algorithm with an output that is 160 bits or shorter can be ruled out for usages that require collisions to be intractable.